# PHP PDO If statement to check if field is empty in delete statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I havent found an answer that suits my needs.

I have a prepared statement to delete data from a table using user input:

```
    $delete = $handler->prepare("DELETE FROM screenings WHERE 
       time = :time    ORDER BY screeningid LIMIT 1; ");
 $delete- >execute(array( ':time' => $screeningtime  ));
```

I'm trying to add an if statement before the delete statement to first check if the record exits, and if so executes the delete statement otherwise  echos an error message.

so far i've been trialling:

```
if(empty($row['column'])) {
 echo "error";
}else {
 //delete statement here
}
```

but to no avail, the error message prints out in all instances

Comment: What is `$row`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I suddenly have no idea, its been a long day, I think i tried to use $screeningtime as $row

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do a SELECT to detect if the row exists.

However, the result of the DELETE would return the number of rows affected, so you could just run it regardless, and then check if 0 or 1 or >1 rows were deleted. That would be `$delete->rowCount()`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: So could I run the delete statement, then:                                                                         `  if ($delete->rowCount() >0 ) { echo "Success"; } else { echo "Failure"; } `

Comment: I've added this below my delete statement, however when I test the result is always "failure"

Comment: @Raznok to assist further, I suggest you update your post with the current version of the code, the value you're passing in for `$screeningtime`, and some sample rows from the table, at least one of which should match `$screeningtime`

Answer (score 0):

```
     <? Php
      $delete->execute();
    if ($delete->rowCount() >= 1)
        echo 'ok';
    else
        echo 'error or not found';
```

Comment: To clarify, using my above example I could use  ` $delete is_removed = $delete->execute `   ?

Comment: @Raznok yes. You can

Comment: `execute` returns True on success, but that won't mean anything was deleted, just means the query itself didn't have errors and executed on the db server. If errors were thrown then it would return False